# Using NDsolve with WhenEvent is not working

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

I am trying to use `WhenEvent` in this nonlinear equation system:

$\ddot r-\dot\phi^2r+9.8(\sin\phi-0.7\cos\phi)=0$

$1.2(1+20(r^2+2^2+4r\sin\phi)^2)\ddot\phi+\dot\phi+\phi=\sin4t$

I want that When $r(t)>1 \Rightarrow r(t)=1$ and When $r(t)<-1 \Rightarrow r(t)=-1$, so I was using the code below:

```
sol = NDSolve[{r''[t] - phi'[t]^2 r[t] + 
     9.8 (Sin[phi[t]] - 0.7*Cos[phi[t]]) == 0, 
   1.2 (1 + 20*(r[t]^2 + 2^2 + 4 r[t] Sin[phi[t]])^2) phi''[t] + 
     phi'[t] + phi[t] == Sin[4 t], 
   phi[0] == phi'[0] == r[0] == r'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[r[t] > 1, r[t] -> 1], 
   WhenEvent[r[t] < -1, r[t] -> -1]}, {r, phi}, {t, 0, 20}]


Plot[r[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}]
```

But when I run the code and plot $r$, I get values bigger than 1... What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can "fix" this by setting `WhenEvent[r[t]>1,r[t]->0.9998]`. This is necessary due to how WhenEvent triggers. However, DO NOT DO THIS. Since your DE is of the second order, it will still tend towards the one anyway since its "velocity" keeps unchanged. Thus you'd just create a very fine sawtooth pattern. So you'd have to set the first derivative as well to get something stable. Something like `WhenEvent[r[t]>1,{r[t]->0.99999,r'[t]->0}]` or even the reflection. (Add PlotRange->All to your plot here)

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try what you have said!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have a misunderstanding here. `r[t]>1` means: the time when r[t] crosses 1 from below and NOT when r[t] is larger than 1. Look it up in the help.

To achieve what you want, that r[t] stays constant after hitting 1, you may define a piecewise function:

```
sol = NDSolve[{1.2 (562500 + 
        1.2*(r[t]^2 + 40^2 + 2*r[t]*40*Sin[phi[t]])) phi''[t] + 
     1030400*phi'[t] + 0.41*phi[t] == 2*Sin [4 t], 
   r''[t] - 0.7*9.8*Cos[phi[t]] + 9.8 Sin[phi[t]] == 0, 
   phi[0] == r[0] == phi'[0] == r'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[r[t] < -1, r[t] -> -1], 
   WhenEvent[r[t] > 1, {r[t] -> 1, tend = t, "StopIntegration"}]
   }, {r[t], phi[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
fun[t_] = 
 Piecewise[{{Evaluate[r[t] /. sol[[1, 1]]], t < tend}, {1, True}}]
```

This gives the following interpolating function:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Plot[fun[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the info!!

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem (autonomous) can be handled by constructing the desired vector field instead of using `WhenEvent`, since the discontinuity (event) depends on the state vector $(r, r', \phi, \phi')$ is independently of what time $t$ is.  One can think of it as *where* versus *when*.  It is possible to handle the problem with `WhenEvent`: wherever the state of the system, it happens some time or another.  The issue with the OP's `WhenEvent` is that it does not change the vector field, and as Julien Kluge [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256855/using-ndsolve-with-whenevent-is-not-working#comment640348_256855), the solution continues to increase from `r[t] == 1` but does not cross it from below, as Daniel Huber [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/256870/4999).

In nonautonomous systems or events, one can use `DiscreteVariables` to turn on/off components of systems as shown in the documentation.  In the OP's problem, we can use `Piecewise` to zero out the `r, r'` components of the vector field.  `NDSolve` will handle the discontinuity for us.  We need to convert the `r` components to a first-order system, so that we can annihilate both `r'[t]` and `r''[t]`.

It's probably easiest to write the `Piecewise` form by hand, but since the OP's system wasn't in `r''[t] ==...` form and my eyes are unreliable, doing it by code was my preference. (It also helps that I knew how to do it by code in a couple of ways.)

```
ode = { (* OP's ode system *)
   r''[t] - phi'[t]^2 r[t] + 9.8 (Sin[phi[t]] - 0.7*Cos[phi[t]]) == 
    0,
   1.2 (1 + 20*(r[t]^2 + 2^2 + 4 r[t] Sin[phi[t]])^2) phi''[t] + 
     phi'[t] + phi[t] == Sin[4 t]};

ode1 = Solve[
     ode~Join~NestList[D[#, t] &, s[t] == r'[t], 1],
      {phi''[t], s'[t], r'[t]}, {r''[t]}] /.  (* eliminates r''[t] *)
    HoldPattern[d : s'[t] | r'[t] -> v_] :> 
     d -> Piecewise[{{v, -1 < r[t] < 1}}] /. Rule -> Equal;
ode1 // Transpose // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The initial conditions were easy to adjust by hand:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
   ode1,
   phi[0] == phi'[0] == r[0] == s[0] == 0}, {r, phi}, {t, 0, 20}];

Plot[r[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]